# NSLocalizedString(key: value: comment: ) with variable is not working in swift

Tags: swift, nslocalizedstring, formatted

I need to localize a string which has some variable and the localized string must be defined with *key: value: comment* format. Guys I tried many ways but don't get the right way yet. See here...

```
let timeValue = 5
let timeString = "hours"

//Bellows are working fine
dateLabelString = String(format: "Overdue by %d %@", timeValue,timeString) //Working  //Normal flat string
dateLabelString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("Overdue by %d %@", comment: "Overdue by 5 days/hours/minutes/seconds"), timeValue,timeString) //Working
dateLabelString = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Overdue by %d %@", comment: "Overdue by 5 days/hours/minutes/seconds"), timeValue,timeString) //Working

dateLabelString = NSString.init(format: "Overdue by %d %@", timeValue,timeString) as String //Working
dateLabelString = NSString.init(format: NSLocalizedString("Overdue by %d %@", comment: "Overdue by 5 days/hours/minutes/seconds"), timeValue,timeString) as String //Working


//Bellows are not working 
dateLabelString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("OVERDUE_BY", value: "Overdue by %d %@", comment: "Overdue by 5 days/hours/minutes/seconds"), timeValue,timeString) //Not Working
dateLabelString = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("OVERDUE_BY", value: "Overdue by %d %@", comment: "Overdue by 5 days/hours/minutes/seconds"), timeValue,timeString) //Not Working
dateLabelString = NSString.init(format: NSLocalizedString("OVERDUE_BY", value: "Overdue by %d %@", comment: "Overdue by 5 days/hours/minutes/seconds"), timeValue,timeString) as String //Not Working
```

*Xcode: 8.2.1  Swift: 2.3*

> Notice the problem is for including the key on NSLocalizedString, otherwise its working perfectly. I need the key must.

Comment: This is a [very good article](https://medium.com/@mendibarouk/enhance-your-localized-capabilities-on-your-ios-applications-d3ba17138077) about localization in Swift for a robust architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For localized strings with variables this is working for me:

```
String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("MyCustomKey", comment: "Hello %d World"), myValue)
```

And in the `Localizable.strings` this line:

```
MyCustomKey = "Hello %d World";
```